# Stencil - Typescript error with html attribute for source-tag

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

i´m currently working on a small project with stenciljs.

As for now, everything went good after some starting issues.

Currently i´m getting an strange error from typescript.

[image]

When im going into the source files for the Types, the property width and height are included in the type.
Unfortunately i can´t find an similiar issue, so i hope someone has an idea.

thanks

Comment: Does the issue persist if you change `width` to be a number, rather than a string?

Comment: yeah, it only resolves if i remove width and height

Comment: So something like doesn't work? 

 `<source srcSet={src} width={200} height={200} media={'YOUR_CONTENT_HERE'} />`

(Note the lack of quotes around the value 200 used for height/width)

Comment: yup, not working. Only if i remove the attributes, thats what i find so strange. my IDE even gives me an autocomplete for width and height. its included in the source types. 

For now, to use the attributes, i changed it to "data-width" and assigend it in my "componendDidRender" hook, but that feels wrong :D

Comment: Yeah, something's not quite right there. Would you be willing/able to open a new issue on the Stencil repo?

Comment: Sure! tomorrow i let it test my working college to test if its not a "just me"-bug! Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround you can add `{/* @ts-ignore */}` to the line before

Comment: For posterity, this was a bug in Stencil. It is going to be fixed in the first release after 4.5.0